# Plot data from several large data files in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have several data files (numeric) with around 150000 rows and 25 columns. Before I was using gnuplot (where script lines are proportional plot objects) to to plot the data but as I have to do now some additional analysis with it I moved to **R** and ggplot2.

How to organize the data, thought? Is one big data.frame with an additional column to mark from which file the data is coming from really the only option? Or is there some way around that?

Edit: To be a bit more precise, I'll give as an example in what form I have the data now:

```
filelst=c("filea.dat", "fileb.dat", "filec.dat")
dat=c()
for(i in 1:length(filelst)) {
    dat[[i]]=read.table(file[i])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have filenames ending with ".dat", here's a mockup example of the strategies proposed by Chase,

```
require(plyr)

# list the files
lf = list.files(pattern = "\.dat")
str(lf)

# 1. read the files into a data.frame
d = ldply(lf, read.table, header = TRUE, skip = 1) # or whatever options to read
str(d) # should contain all the data, and and ID column called L1

# use the data, e.g. plot
pdf("all.pdf")
d_ply(d, "L1", plot, t="l")
dev.off()
# or using ggplot2
ggplot(d, aes(x, y, colour=L1)) + geom_line()

# 2. read the files into a list

ld = lapply(lf, read.table, header = TRUE, skip = 1) # or whatever options to read
names(ld) = gsub("\.dat", "", lf) # strip the file extension
str(ld) 

# use the data, e.g. plot
pdf("all2.pdf")
lapply(names(l), function(ii) plot(l[[ii]], main=ii), t="l")
dev.off()

# 3. is not fun
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little vague. If I followed along properly, I think you have three main options:

1. Do as you suggest and then use any one of the "split-apply-combine" functions that exist in R to conduct your analyses by group. These functions may include `by`, `aggregate`, `ave`, `package(plyr)`, `package(data.table)` and many others.
2. Store your data object as separate elements in a `list()`. Then use `lapply()` and friends to work on them.
3. Keep everything separate in different data objects and work on them individually. This is probably the most inefficient way to go about doing things, unless you have memory constraints et al.

Comment: Thanks! That helps! Could you give an example on the first two points, please?